# How can i Display Map with input and output values?

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to display Google map with user Entered input vales.(source and destination).

Here i have two edit texts one is From And To Based on tha input values we can display the map in Directions Mode.

Comment: do you need to draw route between those two

Comment: yes i want display route

Comment: but you need to get lat and long for both address

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-draw-route-map-between-two.html) to draw driving path in your application. You just need to add the four classes present in the link in your project and call the below lines when you need to display the route.

```
SharedData data = SharedData.getInstance();
data.setAPIKEY("0RUTLH7cqd6yrZ0FdS0NfQMO3lioiCbnH-BpNQQ");//set your map key here
data.setSrc_lat(17);//set your src lat
data.setSrc_lng(78);//set your src lng
data.setDest_lat(18);//set your dest lat
data.setDest_lng(77);//set your dest lng
startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,RoutePath.class));//add RoutePath in your manifeast file
```

//Also add the permission to your manifeast file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```